# Pass filled MVC viewmodel to a controller action via jquery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

I have a page that through the GET action method, fills a complex view model that has lots of properties and few LIST objects.

```
var model = new SelectTargetingViewModel(signupService, orderSignupItem, creativeTemplateId, cultureName, false, dealerMedias.ToList());
```

I am then filling a datatable via AJAX call which right now calls the same code as above.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("~/selecttargeting/getdealermediarates")]
    public ActionResult GetDealerMediaRates(int ordersignupitemId, int? creativeTemplateId)
    {
        appContext.MenuAction = "DealerMediaIndex";
        appContext.MenuController = "Signup";

        string cultureName = "en";

        appContext.SetMenuParametersFromContext();

        var orderSignupItem = signupService.GetOrderSignupItemById(ordersignupitemId);

        var dealermedias = signupService.GetDealerMedias(orderSignupItem.OrderSignupDetail.Order.DealerId, orderSignupItem.OrderSignupDetail.Order.SeasonId, orderSignupItem.PackageMediaType.SeasonMediaType.ClientMediaTypeId);

        var model = new SelectTargetingViewModel(signupService, orderSignupItem, creativeTemplateId, cultureName, false, dealermedias.ToList());

        return PartialView("_GetDealerMediaRate", model);
    }
```

Then call the method via AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDealerMediaRates", "Signup", new { cultureName = Model.CurrentCultureName })?ordersignupitemId=@Model.OrderSignupItemId&creativeTemplateId=@Model.CreativeTemplateId',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                var newHtml = $(data);
                $('.dealermediarates').html(newHtml);
                oTable = $('#targetingtable').DataTable({
                    'aoColumnDefs': [{
                        'bSortable': false,
                        'aTargets': ['nosort']
                    }],
                    'order': [[1, 'asc']],
                    'aLengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, 100, 150, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "All"]],
                    processing: true,
                    "language":
                    {
                        "processing": "<div style='position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 250px; height: 80px; background-color: #fff; text-align: center; z-index: 10; outline: 0 0 0 9999px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border: 1px solid #aaa; padding: 10px 5px;'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Processing...Please wait</div>"
                    }
                });
                oSettings = oTable.settings();
                $('.targetingarea').unblock();
            }
        });
```

This is working but takes longer time to run as its trying to fill the model twice. I am in the process of optimizing the process so instead of filling the main model twice, I want to fill it just once and then pass to my AJAX post method. What I have tried so far is get the model and pass this model as a variable in my method call but when I debug the code, all I see in my model looks like is a default constructor, anything that were initialized using the page get action method, the values are not there anymore. First of all, is this even possible to take the viewmodel and pass this to the method with all of the properties and values, just as if you are doing a HTTP POST? Am I missing anything in the code below.

AJAX CALL

```
var model = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model));
        var datatosend = JSON.stringify(model);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDealerMediaRates", "Signup")',
            type: "POST",
            data: datatosend,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                var newHtml = $(data);
                $('.dealermediarates').html(newHtml);
                oTable = $('#targetingtable').DataTable({
                    'aoColumnDefs': [{
                        'bSortable': false,
                        'aTargets': ['nosort']
                    }],
                    'order': [[1, 'asc']],
                    'aLengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, 100, 150, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "All"]],
                    processing: true,
                    "language":
                    {
                        "processing": "<div style='position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 250px; height: 80px; background-color: #fff; text-align: center; z-index: 10; outline: 0 0 0 9999px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border: 1px solid #aaa; padding: 10px 5px;'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Processing...Please wait</div>"
                    }
                });
                oSettings = oTable.settings();
                $('.targetingarea').unblock();
            }
        });
```

GET Method on the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("~/selecttargeting/getdealermediarates")]
    public ActionResult GetDealerMediaRates(SelectTargetingViewModel model)
    {
        appContext.MenuAction = "DealerMediaIndex";
        appContext.MenuController = "Signup";

        return PartialView("_GetDealerMediaRate", model);
    }
```

When I debug and look at the model below in the POST method, I am seeing that the model is not NULL but it looks like its being initialized with a default constructor. If this is not even possible, I will work towards a different solution but thought to check if I am missing anything.